# specifying linux kernel md not checking v1.2 superblock

Tags: linux-kernel, raid, mdadm

I am trying to boot a Linux software raid array without an initramfs.
I am passing `md=0,/dev/nvme0n1p1,/dev/nvme1n1p1 root=/dev/md0` to the kernel.
I have also tried `md=d0,..` to no avail.

Examining the kernel log leads me to believe it is only checking v0.0 and v0.90 but not v1.2:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1 does not have a valid v0.0 superblock, not importing!
...
/dev/nvme0n1p1 does not have a valid v0.90 superblock, not importing!
```

The kernel then panics since `/dev/md0` could not be constructed due to failures and therefore cannot use it as a root device.

What could be causing this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, it's not supported unless you use v0.90 metadata for your rootfs (and linux raid partition type). `md=` is part of md-autodetect and it only supports legacy stuff.

Comment: @frostschutz I see. Is using an initramfs the only viable method then?

Comment: There is also early setup of dm devices via kernel parameters but it has limited support for setting up dm-raid as well. So without initramfs, mdadm 0.90 version md-autodetect raid is your only choice. Or some kind of hardware raid that doesn't require setup. I'd just go with initramfs though...

Comment: Right, thanks for this!